# Combine more than 2 Smarty Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

When using array_combine I'm able to combine two array and use the loop through. In the example below I can us $title in my HTML.

```
{foreach array_combine($p_titles, $p_prices) as $title => $price}<!--SOME HTML-->{/foreach}
```

However if I try to add another array to this solution it breaks. My local host isn't displaying an error other than "Page not Working "localhost is currently unable to handle this request."

```
{foreach array_combine($p_titles, $p_prices, $p_ids) as $title => $price => $id}<!--SOME HTML-->{/foreach}
```

How do I combine 3 or more arrays using this method.

Comment: Changing what you have posted after someone gives in answer is not cool. This disables people that search similar queries to find the right answer.

Comment: I would assume labelling the question better would help people find it. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide what you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you tagged `Javascript` however what you have shown in you question is PHP.

Second, the `array_combine` only accepts two parameters. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

To use `array_combine` for three arrays do this:

```
$combinedArray = array_combine($p_titles, $p_prices);
$combinedArray = array_combine($combinedArray, $p_ids);
```

---

**Edit**: Answer that matches your code in normal PHP syntax.

```
$result = array();

foreach($p_titles as $key => $value)
{
    $result[$value] = array('price' => $p_prices[$key], 'id' => $p_ids[$key]);
}

echo($result);
```

You can access this data like these: `$result['title']['price']` or `$result['title']['id'];`

---

**Edit 2**: And the `Smarty` code.

I'm not that familiar with `Smarty` syntax so this might not work:

```
{ $result = array(); }

{ foreach from=$p_titles key=key item=value }

    { $result[$value] = array('price' => $p_prices[$key], 'id' => $p_ids[$key]) }

{ /foreach }
```

Comment: In the example given I was using the method {foreach}. However can I use this with your solution. Create a variable from each array like before. ie. {$title}.

Comment: I have just left work, and am unable to update my answer. If you wait for me to get home, I would be happy to provide you with an answer that matches your code.

Comment: Could you help?